# PyGobject TreeView Columns re-sized when selected

Tags: python, pygobject

I am writing an Application in Python which uses a TreeView with a few columns.

When a row is double clicked or selected, the TreeView's column start changing their size a few times and then settle down. (Looks a bit like when auto-configuring a display).

What can cause this problem?

**Related Code:**

[ui.glade](http://pastebin.com/bfanvM1N) |
[main.py](http://pastebin.com/9SCdTyN5)

https://bitbucket.org/Gilnaa/treeoflifepublic/src

Comment: Please provide a working minimal example. The files provided cannot be launched:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
        from models import *
    ImportError: No module named models

Comment: @Havok I've added a link to the full source